# Keyword `this` problem with using in ajax function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

ok this is some crazy jquery code that I have here. what its doing is going to a php file to get results of some sort and then slide down the results but if the results are already there just slide down

```
$('#compatibility h2').click(function(){
        var clicked = $(this);
        if($(this).hasClass('collapsed'))
        {
            $(clicked).removeClass('collapsed');
            if($($(this)[0].nextSibling).is('ul'))
            {
                $(this).next().slideToggle();
            }
            else
            {
            $.get("getproducts.php", {cid: $(this).attr('id'), did: $("#deviceId").val()},
                  function(data)
                  {   
                    $(clicked).after(data).next().slideToggle(); //adds a <ul> <li> </li> </ul>  
                  });
            }
        }
        else
        {

            $(this).addClass('collapsed');  
            $(this).next().slideToggle();
        }
        //$(this).css('margin','4px 0 7px');
});
```

now my question is kind of obscure but i was wondering why when I replace clicked with the keyword `this` the code does not insert the data after the h2 that was clicked. Also I am wondering if I am doing this in the best way with jquery.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is a little vague.  What is `this` actually set to?

Comment: is it because when I go into the ajax function this is no longer pointing to the clicked element?

Comment: You replace clicked with `this` *everywhere*!?!  No, `this` is *not* included in the closure and *will* be set to something *different* in an enclosed function.  Your first like should be `var clicked = this;` to stash the value.

Comment: thats what I was asking pretty much I noticed that at the end everyone had good answers to my problem thanks I do however have a problem with the line of if($($(this)[0].nextSibling).is('ul')) is there a better way to find if the next sibling of the clicked element is an ul

Comment: How about `if ($(this).next().is('ul'))` ?  Same thing but more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first glance, I would think that using "this" would everywhere except inside your $.get(...).  One trick that I use sometimes to get around callbacks and multiple versions of "this" is to add the following code at the top of my class or function:

```
var me = this;
```

Then I just use `$(me)` instead of `$(this)`

Comment: yeah I understood at least where it might be going wrong when I asked the question

Answer (score 5):

Why are you doing this? `var clicked = '#'+$(this).attr('id');`?

This should work:

```
var clicked = $(this);
```

Comment: +1. this inside jQuery call refers to the css selector on which you are executing the function.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in line 10 or so where he says:

```
$(clicked).after(data).next().slideToggle(); //adds a <ul> <li> </li> </ul>
```

If you replace `clicked` with `this` there, it will stop working: `this` will be pointing to the response from the `$.get` not any DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

Lines 2 and 3 look very wrong to me, if what you're doing is what I think you're doing then what you're doing is building a string '#' + id_of_clicked_element, and then trying to run jQuery operations on it.  That's never going to work!  And it's also unnecessary.

Just `if ($(this).hasClass ('collapsed'))` should do fine.